# Shiny app multiple regression

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Linear model DARP"),


  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(

     sliderInput(inputId = "area",
                 "select the service region area:",
                 min= 170,
                 max= 8000,
                 value=1001),
     sliderInput(inputId = "crit..peak",
                 label="Choose Peak demand:",
                 min=10,
                 max=150,
                 value=39)
  ),


  mainPanel(
     tableOutput("table")
  )
  )
  )


server <- function(input, output) {

   output$table <- renderTable({

    df_ln<-read.csv("F:/Project/Programme/ML/DAR Machine Learning TR Part A/train_darp_ln.csv")
Linearmodel_DARP<-lm(veh~area+crit..peak,data = df_ln)
 new_demand1<-data.frame(area=input$area)
 new_demand2<-data.frame(crit..peak=input$crit..peak
 fleetsize<-predict(Linearmodel_DARP,newdata=c(new_demand1,new_demand2))
 round(exp(fleetsize),0)
})
}
```

`shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`
 I am getting error object crit..peak is not found when running the app
The app should take two inputs from the user through the slider and based on the multiple regression it will give a prediction of the predict command 
please help as I need to do it soon for a project

```
structure(list(area = c(2217.7, 6537.4, 1705.5, 5634, 1260.5, 
4797.7), density = c(0.13753, 0.016826, 0.18469, 0.021477, 0.25862, 
0.027305), crit..CV = c(0.63954, 0.81437, 0.49909, 0.33935, 0.39148, 
0.17489), crit..peak = c(49L, 26L, 41L, 20L, 39L, 18L), TW = c(21L, 
47L, 54L, 48L, 17L, 41L), L = c(569L, 576L, 391L, 390L, 458L, 
392L), s = c(7L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L), speed = c(18L, 26L, 20L, 
30L, 24L, 33L), circuity = c(1.3284, 1.1494, 1.4597, 1.2725, 
1.0486, 1.0792), cap = c(9L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 7L), mrt = c(1.5452, 
2.3743, 1.5962, 2.6065, 2.1278, 2.6228), veh = c(4.605170186, 
3.433987204, 4.718498871, 3.951243719, 4.060443011, 3.526360525
), veh.hrs = c(6.665569062, 5.523778231, 6.496186582, 5.71857256, 
5.816843267, 5.256713817), veh.km = c(9.555940819, 8.781874769, 
9.491918855, 9.119769942, 8.994897097, 8.753221378)), .Names = c("area", 
"density", "crit..CV", "crit..peak", "TW", "L", "s", "speed", 
"circuity", "cap", "mrt", "veh", "veh.hrs", "veh.km"), row.names = c(NA, 
 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please post a minimal sample of your data in the text of your question. Read this to see how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, crit..peak is a variable name in data frames.I want to build a regression model using the original data and want to predict from the user input two variables i.e area and crit..peak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so your problem is probably due to the way you try to make your new data frame. You made two separate 1 dimensional data frames and then concatenated them, which generated a list of dataframes. To make a data frame with two or more variables, define them in your data frame definition or use `cbind` to join the data frames together:

```
 new_demand <- data.frame(area = input$area,
                          crit..peak = input$crit..peak)
 fleetsize <- predict(Linearmodel_DARP, newdata = new_demand)
```

This should solve your problem. In the future, when you get errors like `error object ... is not found`, the first thing to do is check that the objects you're generating are what you think they are. The `class` function would have told you that `c(new_demand1, new_demand2)` is a `list` not a `data.frame`

Comment: Yeah your solution helped Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me how to reactively input the resonse variable and get the prediction based on the selected variable in the same model

Comment: `Linearmodel_DARP<-lm(df_ln[[input$response_var]]~area+crit..peak,data = df_ln)`

Comment: To select the response variable by passing a character string provided by some responsive input object, you need to use ``[[]]`` notation, rather than just providing the bare variable name

Comment: `data(cars); lm(speed~dist,data=cars)` gives the same result as:

`data(cars); lm(cars[['speed']]~dist,data=cars)`

Answer (score 0):

The error could be because of `read.csv` as it's missing `header = T`.

Let's try this chunk of code

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    df_ln <- read.csv("F:/Project/Programme/ML/DAR Machine Learning TR Part A/train_darp_ln.csv", header = T)
    Linearmodel_DARP <- lm(veh~area+chrit..peak, data = df_ln)
    new_demand1 <- data.frame(area=input$area)
    new_demand2 <- data.frame(crit..peak=input$crit..peak)
    fleetsize <- predict(Linearmodel_DARP, newdata=c(new_demand1, new_demand2))
    round(exp(fleetsize), 0)
  })
}
```